# Adding an image to HTML code from the web

Tags: html, image

I would like to add a picture in my code that is not from my computer, but from the web. Let's say that the link of the image is "www.image.test", how would the code be written? And, what if I want to hide a link behind that image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. The code would look like this. The `<a href>` will add a link to the image when clicked on, and the `<img>` tag will add the image from the appropriate image URL that you would specify.

```
<a href="http://www.examplelink.com"><img src="http://www.image.test"></a>
```